# Python: Easygui Window Size

Tags: python, easygui

I'm creating a GUI for my python script in EasyGUI. Does anyone know of a way I can change the default Window size? The default is far too big.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before install open `easygui.py` and edit element you want to have another size. (You can also reinstall and override it)
This will be line like

```
boxRoot.minsize(root_width, root_height)
```

in the corresponfing function.
To be more flexible add width and height as parameters to the function.

```
def __choicebox(msg
               , title
               , choices
               , width_ = 480
               , height_ = 320
               ):
 ....
  root_width    = width_
  root_height   = height_
  root_xpos     = int((screen_width * 0.1))
  root_ypos     = int((screen_height * 0.05))

  boxRoot.title(title)
  boxRoot.iconname('Dialog')
  rootWindowPosition = "+0+0"
  boxRoot.geometry(rootWindowPosition)
  boxRoot.expand=NO
  boxRoot.minsize(root_width, root_height)
```

Answer (score 1):

I pseudo-pulled the code from GitHub to mess with the choicebox because of the size problem and I did the following .... I don't know if this is a good fix or not but it seemed to work to make at least the width of the screen variable according to the length of msg, title, and list of choices:

...
choices = list(choices[:])

## add lines

```
choiceLen = len(max(choices,key=len))
titleLen = len(title)
msgLen = len(msg)
maxLen = max(choiceLen,titleLen,msgLen)
```

...

## root_width = int((screen_width * 0.8))

```
root_width = int(maxLen * 10.)
```

Comment: Sometimes a choice list can be quite wide, for instance I have used tabulate to create a file from a dataframe ... so this is better to check on the width of the list to determine the width of the screen:      if (int((screen_width * 0.8)) < int(maxLen * 10.)):
        root_width = int((screen_width * 0.8))
    else:
        root_width = int(maxLen * 10.)